# Ambassador Edge Stack JWT filter with Firebase token not working

Tags: firebase, kubernetes, jwt, api-gateway, ambassador

I'm trying to verify a Firebase generated JWT token with an Ambassador Edge Stack (datawire/edge-stack version 3.3.0) Filter.

The Firebase token is generated using a login/password authent mechanism on firebase, something like (in Python):

```py
    email=input("Enter email: ")
    password=input("Enter password: ")
    user = authentication.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
    custom_token = auth.create_custom_token(user["localId"], additional_claims)
    print("JWT Token :")
    print(custom_token)
```

After the token is generated, I use it with a curl command such as:

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://ambassador-ip.nip.io/hello-world/
```

and the curl command returns the following error:

```bash
        },
        "message": "Token validation error: token is invalid: errorFlags=0x00000002=(ValidationErrorUnverifiable) wrappedError=(KeyID=\"50***redacted***1\": JWK not found)",
        "status_code": 401
}
```

Here is the ambassador Filter I've declared:

```yaml
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Filter
metadata:
  name: "firebase-filter"
  namespace: ${kubernetes_namespace.hello_world.metadata[0].name}
spec:
  JWT:
    jwksURI:  "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    audience: "${local.project_id}"
    issuer:   "https://securetoken.google.com/${local.project_id}"
```

And the policy filter applied to my backend:

```yaml
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v3alpha1
kind: FilterPolicy
metadata:
  name: "firebase-filter-policy"
  namespace: ${kubernetes_namespace.hello_world.metadata[0].name}
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "*"
    path: "/hello-world/"
    filters:                    
    - name: "firebase-filter"
      namespace: "${kubernetes_namespace.hello_world.metadata[0].name}"
```

For the record, the curl command with the same token works on a deployed hello-world Cloud Run with a GCP API gateway configured as follow:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Example Firebase auth Gateway
  description: API Gateway with firebase auth
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
securityDefinitions:
  firebase:
    authorizationUrl: ''
    flow: implicit
    type: oauth2
    x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/${project_id}"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-audiences: "${project_id}"
paths:
  /v1/hello:
    get:
      security:
        - firebase: []
      description: Hello
      operationId: hello
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
      x-google-backend:
        address: 'https://hello-redacted-ew.a.run.app'
```

Any idea why the Ambassador filter is misconfigured ?

Answer (score 1):

Ambassador JWT Filter needs the jwksURI to point to the Firebase secure token service account public keys and not the X509 certificates, therefore the Filter should be:

```yaml
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Filter
metadata:
  name: "firebase-filter"
  namespace: ${kubernetes_namespace.hello_world.metadata[0].name}
spec:
  JWT:
    jwksURI:  "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    audience: "${local.project_id}"
    issuer:   "https://securetoken.google.com/${local.project_id}"
```

This is working for Firebase tokens only. If you want to make this works with Custom tokens using some dedicated service account for example, you might need the jwksURI to point to your service account public keys, something like:

```yaml
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Filter
metadata:
  name: "firebase-custom-filter"
  namespace: ${kubernetes_namespace.hello_world.metadata[0].name}
spec:
  JWT:
    jwksURI:  "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/${service_account}@${local.project_id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    audience: "${local.project_id}"
    issuer:   "https://securetoken.google.com/${local.project_id}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The JWT Filter requires you to provide the url for the `.well-known/openid-configuration` so that it can verify the signature of the token. I'm not familiar with Firebase but looking on their docs it appears you can find this here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/openid-connect

For example your Filter should be configured something like the following (*i'm guessing on the jwksURI*):

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Filter
metadata:
  name: "firebase-filter"
  namespace: ${kubernetes_namespace.hello_world.metadata[0].name}
spec:
  JWT:
    jwksURI:  "https://securetoken.google.com/${local.project_id}/.well-known/openid-configuration"
    audience: "${local.project_id}"
    issuer:   "https://securetoken.google.com/${local.project_id}"
```

Comment: Hi Lance, thanks for answering. I've actually figured out the issue. The public jwksURI to tell ambassador is the actual Firebase service account public key list, not the X.509 certificates. I will post a complete answer for those facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear you were able to solve it!